# Selenium Webdriver use SendKeys() without overwriting field contents

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Problem: How can I use SendKeys() or something similar to continue editing in a field without erasing the existing contents.

I am using Selenium Webdriver in C#. I am trying to automate this type of dialog (shown below) in which you can make multiple selections one after the other. I can select the first entry easily with `driver.[some_selector].SendKeys("Blueberry");`

At this point the focus is in the next field. I send a shift-tab to get the focus back in this dialog, with the cursor immediately after the first selection. But every subsequent use of .SendKeys() replaces the contents of the input box, so I can never achieve more than one selection.

Just as a test I have also tried something like .SendKeys(firstField+Keys.Enter+secondField) to no avail.

Is there a use of SendKeys() or an alternate method that will continue typing in a populated field but leave the existing contents alone? Or not leave the current field after entry?

(If it is of any interest, I believe this is a angular ui-select2 component)

[image: tag selection dialog]

Comment: Not sure exactly about your scenario, but if your objective is to preserve what you have already typed and want to type more, you can just gettext() store and append in the next SendKeys().

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that won't work in this case. I hoped the screenshot would provide context, but you have to type some characters, select an option, type some more characters, select second option, etc. I can't, for example, just select Blueberry, Lemon, Mango in one go.

Comment: Sample html would help. Have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: lloyd - It's basically a Select Option dialog, but select2 is an angular wrapped jquery plugin (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) so "sample html" in this case is hard to achieve. What would be ideal is a live example but I may not be able to provide that.
I can use jquery if needed. What did you have in mind? 
Ideally I'd like to find out what is possible with SendKeys() or something else in WebDriver. 
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Some example page helps me to catch it correctly, sorry for that. After selecting first element, shift-tab is used to focus on required element. After that, as said using sendkeys, with locator? is that locator is unique to new active element?

Is used     "driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("selenium");" in java to enter text where the cursor is blinking or active. did you tried this one after shift-tab? I got success with this command back ago, some what similar to this issue..

Thank You

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Thus far this and other approaches (including trying to set focus with Javascript) have had no effect. Meaning, the element never gets focus. As mentioned above I can overwrite the field no problem, but click(), focus(), etc. don't set the cursor in the field. I will update this if I find a solution.